# STM32H723 ADC3 Hardware Auto-Calibration Behaving Unexpectedly

Tags: adc, rtd, stm32h

I am trying to read from the ADC3 module of an STM32H723. ADC1 and ADC2 have been previously set up, although I was using a manually added constant offset rather than the automatic calibration in section 29.4.8 of the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0468-stm32h723733-stm32h725735-and-stm32h730-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

After noticing an offset of about 130 counts in the ADC reading, I discovered the automatic calibration feature, which I would want to use in the future since the chip may be experiencing large temperature swings where the offset may change, as advised in the datasheet.

I ran the following code, which seems to fix the issue in converting the output voltage. I get ADC count values that make sense for both a test resistor, open circuit, and actual RTDs.

```
HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc3);
HAL_StatusTypeDef status3 =  HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc3, ADC_CALIB_OFFSET, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc3);
```

I did however run into 2 issues. The ADC_CALFACT register does not seem to be written by the calibration process. There is clearly an offset in the raw ADC readings, but the following function returns zero, and inspecting the hardware registers confirms it.
HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_GetValue(&hadc1, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);

The larger, and more concerning, issue is that running the same hardware calibration on a combination of ADC 1 and ADC 2 causes the values produced by ADC 3 to become nonsensical, off by hundreds of degrees. As an example, when connecting RTDs at room temperature (slightly above 1kR), I get the following counts compared to the 4095 maximum on the 2 channels of ADC 3 respectively:

- No calibration: 1023, 2263
- ADC 3 calibrated: 2137, 2136
- ADCs 1 and 3 calibrated: 895,2135  ADCs
  1 and 2 calibrated: 1791, 1023
- ADCs 2 and 3    calibrated: 895, 2135
- All ADCs calibrated: 1671, 895

I am wondering what could be causing this issue. I have tried with another copy of the same board, so I imagine it is something in the code. I've probed the voltages on the board and they make sense as well.

This is the sensing circuit, with the opamp output routed directly to the MCU pin. The VREF+ input comes from the same 3V reference.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.